# How can I simplify the codes without affect the output?

Tags: c++

I am having my C++ classes and I have done the assignment which is second code at first but then it will appear weird output while default case like Invalid Vehicle Code
RM6.95265e-308. Then I change it to the first code which is working well but too long. Any ideas to simplify it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char vCode;
    double vRate; // Toll rate for the vehicle
    double toll, distance;

    cout << "Enter vehicle code: " << endl;
    cin >> vCode; // C-Car, B-Bus, T-Truck, M-Motorbike


    cout << "Enter the distance travelled by the vehicle (in km): " << endl;
    cin >> distance;

    switch(vCode)
    {
        case 'C' : cout << "vRate = 50%" << endl;
        vRate = 0.50;
            toll = vRate * distance;
                cout << "RM " << toll << endl;
            break;
        case 'B' : cout << "vRate = 85%" << endl;
        vRate = 0.85;
            toll = vRate * distance;
                cout << "RM " << toll << endl;
            break;
        case 'T' : cout << "vRate = 100%" << endl;
        vRate = 1.00;
            toll = vRate * distance;
                cout << "RM " << toll << endl;
            break;
        case 'M' : cout << "Free toll" << endl;
        vRate = 0.00;
            toll = vRate * distance;
                cout << "RM " << toll << endl;
            break;
        default  : cout << "Invalid Vehicle Code" << endl;
            break;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

It looks too long and complicated. Any ideas to simplify it?
When I use the other code which is shorter like the code below it will appear weird output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char vCode;
    double vRate; // Toll rate for the vehicle
    double toll, distance;
    
    cout << "Enter vehicle code: " << endl;
    cin >> vCode; // C-Car, B-Bus, T-Truck, M-Motorbike

    cout << "Enter the distance travelled by the vehicle (in km): " << endl;
    cin >> distance;
    
    switch(vCode)
    {
        case 'C' : cout << "vRate = 50%" << endl;
        vRate = 0.5;
        break;
        case 'B' : cout << "vRate = 85%" << endl;
        vRate = 0.85;
        break;
        case 'T' : cout << "vRate = 100%" << endl;
        vRate = 1.00;
        break;
        case 'M' : cout << "Free toll" << endl;
        vRate = 0.00;
        break;
        default  : cout << "Invalid Vehicle Code" << endl;
    }
    
    toll = vRate * distance;
    cout << "RM" <<toll << endl; 
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the first code example works but the second one doesn't? Also, you have a `z` in there which is a typo.

Comment: I dont see any issues with the second code. What's the input that you supplied? Was that one of upper code C/B/T/M?

Comment: @SMA The second version prints `"RM" <<toll` even for invalid vehicle codes and the first version doesn't. That also means that in the second version `toll = vRate * distance;` sometimes relies on an uninitialized `vRate` variable.

Comment: sorry, the z was the typo. The answer gives me a good solution which is assigned the vRate=0 but what if I don't want the RM0 from the output Invalid Vehicle Code
RM0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of weird output is during default case No value is assigned to **vRate** so the compiler assigns a garbage value so u ended up with some weird ouptut to over come this error assign the `vRate = 0` while declaring so you will overcome this error.

And there is a `z` in second code which is a typo.

The corrected code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char vCode;
    double vRate = 0; // Toll rate for the vehicle
    double toll, distance;
    
    cout << "Enter vehicle code: " << endl;
    cin >> vCode; // C-Car, B-Bus, T-Truck, M-Motorbike

    cout << "Enter the distance travelled by the vehicle (in km): " << endl;
    cin >> distance;
    
    switch(vCode)
    {
        case 'C' : cout << "vRate = 50%" << endl;
        vRate = 0.5;
        break;
        case 'B' : cout << "vRate = 85%" << endl;
        vRate = 0.85;
        break;
        case 'T' : cout << "vRate = 100%" << endl;
        vRate = 1.00;
        break;
        case 'M' : cout << "Free toll" << endl;
        vRate = 0.00;
        break;
        default  : cout << "Invalid Vehicle Code" << endl;
    }
    toll = vRate * distance;
    cout << "RM" <<toll << endl; 
}
```

Comment: sorry, the z was the typo. Your answer gives me a good solution which is assigned the vRate=0 but what if I don't want the RM0 from the output Invalid Vehicle Code RM0?

Comment: In that case you need an if statement to check if it is a valid or not.

Comment: Thank you, my friend. I will try.